# Competition with three winners

Tags: probability, probability-theory

12 people participate in the competition. Among them 3 will become winners. 4 members are members of my family. What is the probability that at least one member of my family will win?

I tried to solve it like this:

```
 (3 / 12) + (2 / 11) + (1 / 10) = 0,531818181818182
```

but this is the probability that one person will win. If you multiply this by 4, the probability will be more than 2.

How do I solve this task?

P.S. This is not a task from a textbook, this is an example from my life.

P.P.S. Sorry, but I used google translator to write this question. I hope someone understands what is written here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that the any set of $3$ persons has the same probability to be the set of the winners then 
$$\frac{\binom{12-4}{3}}{\binom{12}{3}}=\frac{\binom{8}{3}}{\binom{12}{3}}=\frac{8\cdot 7\cdot 6}{12\cdot 11\cdot 10}=\frac{14}{55}$$
is the probability that no members of your family is a winner, and therefore the complement
$$1-\frac{14}{55}=\frac{41}{55}\approx 0.7454$$
is the probability that at least one member of my family is a winner.

Comment: What? 14/55? Expression and response are not equal. (8/3)/(12/3) = 0,666666666(6)

Comment: They are binomial coefficients https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: ooooh, sorry. I thought it was fractions

Comment: I'm used to another notation for binomial coefficients

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!